# Why the second query does not work?

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I use ajax to call a php file to do the sql query.
When the user press a button, the php file does some queries including one select and two insert.
It works fine when the user press the button for the first time. In the second time, only the select query and the first insert query works, the second insert query does not insert anything. I have checked the query, it is all fine. It seems by some reason the second insert query is not executed.

```
$itemquery = "insert into `Items` values (...)";
if($affected_rows = $db->exec($itemquery) ){
    ...
    $pickupquery = "insert into `Pickup` values (...)";
    if ($affected_rows2 = $db->exec($pickupquery)) {
        echo "success";
    }
    else echo "No pickup is inserted";
}
```

For the first time I press the button, both query works fine (outputs "success"). Items are inserted into tables.
But the second time I press it, only the $itemquery works, the $pickupquery does not insert anything (outputs "No pickup is inserted").
The $pickupquery itself has no problems, but I don't know why it just not work after the first press.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you inspected your database directly (using phpMyAdmin, mysql CLI, etc...) after running the first query?

Comment: You might get a MySQL error the 2nd time

Comment: The `Pickup` table may have a constraint that fails the second time with the same values.

Comment: Of course, and the $pickupquery won't insert anything after the first press, with no errors, just not inserting anything...

Comment: Sorry bros, yes, because I set one attribute to be unique but the second time it inserts with the same value which blocks the insert. It is a stupid problem. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake that I set on attribute to unique in the database, and I tried to insert a duplicated value, which caused the problem. There was not any problem for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax is incorrect. It should be

```
INSERT INTO `Items` (COL_NAMES) VALUES (a, b,...)
```

for example

```
INSERT INTO `Items` (`name`, `price`) VALUES ('Beans', 0.40);
```

Comment: The column names, though advisable, is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You could also insert into SQL like this (Though I'm not sure if this is better or worse, but it is easier):

```
INSERT INTO `Items` SET name='Beans', price='0.40'
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think we have enough information to answer this. It could be a javascript issue, it could be a unique index on the db that prevents the inserting or the same values the second time etc.

To start debugging it you should use Firebug. With Firebug you should copy the link that gets called with Ajax and try to access it directly from the browser. Refresh the page afterwards to see if you get any errors, this should simulate pressing the button 2 times with Ajax.

Check with difebug that the ajax calls are calling the correct page and that it calls it 2 times (1 for each press of the button).

Then check to see if there are any errors in the error files defined for that host.